# Do creepers attack villagers?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I found traces of explosion (and missing villagers) in my village.

Did villagers aggro some creepers, or was it someone else on the server?

Comment: Next time could you tell us if it's in SMP or in Single Player ? :)

Comment: It is SMP. I thought it could be inferred from the words "someone other from the server" :-)

Comment: It may not have been a griefer.  Mobs can sometimes accidentally trigger aggro on each other, and if one triggered it on a creeper, it could have resulted in this explosion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, only zombies attack the villagers. A creeper may have tried to blow up someone else or else it could have been a griefer.

Answer (score 1):

The creepers wont attack villagers. Only zombies will and sometimes during a siege they will gang up on one villagers door and break it down allowing them to kill the creeper inside!!
A creeper could also blow up but this is highly unlikely as the player is the only one who can anger it.

Answer (score 1):

Creepers don't attack villagers. It was probably a griefer.

Answer (score 0):

Minecraft is created such that creepers cannot attack villagers. Other mobs such as the zombie and griefer will attack a villager. However, creepers may kill or damage villagers if you (or another player) agitates it. Happy playing!  :)

Answer (score 0):

It was probably a player that triggered the creeper. My theory of why creepers don't attack villagers is because iron golems are friends with creepers, and iron golems protect villagers.